# HTML 5/ Javascript canvas Loading image error

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I am trying to load an image inside a function, but the image is not showing on the screen. There are no console errors so i don't know why it will not work.
Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var score = 0;
var menuImg = new Image();
menuImg.src = "images/Startscreen.png";

gamemenu();

//The menu screen
function gamemenu(){
    ctx.drawImage(menuImg,0,0);
}
```

The image should draw when the function is called but it does not, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading an image is an asynchronous process so you need to add an event handler for the "load" event.

```
menuImg = new Image();
menuImg.addEventListener("load", function () {
    gamemenu();
}, false);
```

I deal with this on a regular basis in my projects since we make heavy use of canvas and sprite rendering.

Update: Here's [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) about this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  i will be sure to try this out :)

Comment: @corrigan_sam make sure you bind the event handler before setting the src property of the image object.